# space between two circles when one cuts another

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I need to arrange two `UIImageView`s in the following way, where one cuts another with some space inbetween each other as shown in the following example:

[image: space circles]

I can't use `borderWidth` because I need transparency around the green circle. There is a background image view in my app, so with the `borderWidth` users would see a black border line around the image or they would see nothing if I use `clearColor`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a layer mask to achieve this.

***Swift 2.3***

```
let mask = CAShapeLayer()
let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

let center = view.convertPoint(statusImageView.center, toView: profileImageView)
let radius = statusImageView.frame.width / 2 + 4

CGPathAddRect(path, nil, profileImageView.bounds)
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, center.x, center.y, radius, 0, CGFloat(2 * M_PI), false)

mask.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
mask.path = path

profileImageView.layer.mask = mask
profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

***Swift 3***

```
let mask = CAShapeLayer()
let path = CGMutablePath()

path.addRect(profileImageView.bounds)
path.addArc(
    center: view.convert(statusImageView.center, to: profileImageView),
    radius: statusImageView.frame.width / 2 + 4,
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: CGFloat(2 * M_PI),
    clockwise: false
)

mask.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
mask.path = path

profileImageView.layer.mask = mask
profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

***UPDATE***

```
class MatchViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet var matchedImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var profileImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var tickImageView: UIImageView!

    // MARK: Properties

    var innerContainer: UIView! { return profileImageView.superview }
    var outerContainer: UIView! { return innerContainer?.superview }

    // MARK: Lifecycle

    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle { return .LightContent }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let mask = CAShapeLayer(),
            path = CGPathCreateMutable()

        let center = outerContainer.convertPoint(tickImageView.center, toView: innerContainer),
            radius = tickImageView.frame.width / 2 + 4

        CGPathAddRect(path, nil, innerContainer.bounds)
        CGPathAddArc(path, nil, center.x, center.y, radius, 0, CGFloat(2 * M_PI), false)

        mask.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        mask.path = path

        innerContainer?.layer.mask = mask
        innerContainer?.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Make sure your views are structured like this.

[image: Storyboard]

This should be the result. *Should* be.

[image: Simulator]

Comment: Thanx! I tried and got error `CGMutablePath` cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers. I use xcode 8 and swift 2.3

Comment: Oh I assumed you were using swift 3

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to implement this in `viewDidAppear` of my View Controller but nothing changes. I tried to `setNeedsDisplay()` for profileImage and `layoutIfNeeded()` It doesn't help also.

Comment: cool and one of the storyboard and it running in simulator please

Comment: [stroryboard](http://imgur.com/vGOa6X2) and [simulator](http://imgur.com/tRtFJ35)
Sorry can't take full screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126720/discussion-between-ilya-and-callam).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a clipping for the image, and a custom view instead of an `UIImageView`. For computing the clipping path you need the [intersection of two circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256100/how-can-i-find-the-points-at-which-two-circles-intersect).